# POSTリクエストを送った後、言語切替をするとindexアクションにルーティングされてしまう

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, i18n

以下のコードで、アプリのヘッダーから言語切替ができるようにしました。

```
<% if I18n.locale.to_s == "ja" %>
  <li class="nav-item">
     <%= link_to "Việt / 日本語", {:locale => "vi"}, {class: "nav-link"} %>
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li class="nav-item">
     <%= link_to "Việt / 日本語", {:locale => "ja"}, {class: "nav-link"} %>
  </li>
<% end %>

ルーティング(一部)
users GET    (/:locale)/users(.:format)       users#index {:locale=>/ja|vi/}
      POST   (/:locale)/users(.:format)       users#create {:locale=>/ja|vi/}
```

例えば、会員登録に失敗した後、このボタンを押すとGETリクエストと認識されてindexにルーティングされるのですが、
会員登録ページのまま、言語だけ切替える方法は無いのでしょうか。

```
users GET    (/:locale)/users(.:format)       users#new {:locale=>/ja|vi/}
```

こちらを追加すると解決できそうですが、今度はindexアクションへのルーティングが成り立たなくなります。
どうすればよいか教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 会員登録はどうやって行っているのでしょうか？　gemを利用しているならそのgem名を、自前で行っているならその関連のソースがわかるよう、質問を編集したほうがいいと思います。また、会員登録に失敗したあと言語変更するというのは、その部分だけ聞くと普通やらない（やらせない）操作に思えたりするので、そのタイミングでも必要になる理由などもあるといいです。

Comment: 返信が遅れてしまい、申し訳ございませんでした。
仰るとおり、そもそも必要な操作には思えなかったため、言語切替時はTOPページに遷移させるように組み直しました。
今後は質問の仕方に気を付けます。

Comment: こちらこそ、そういう意図はなかったのですが、読み直してみると書き方が強い感じになっていたようで、すみません。